# pandas subplot useoffset=False

Tags: pandas

How do I tell pandas' `DataFrame.plot(subplots=True...)`  not to use an offset on the tick labels?

Normally for a single plot I can issue:

`matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False)`

but it doesn't seem to work for the subplot option.

Answer (score 6):

Plotting a dataframe (df here below) with the option suplots=True creates for each column of your dataframe an axis. It is needed to iterate on all axes to set the ticklabel_format.

```
In [59]: axes = df.plot(subplots=True)

In [60]: for axis in axes:
   ....:     axis.ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False)
```

Comment: This doesn't to work anymore...

Comment: axis[0].ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False)